# Как получить длину массива?

Tags: mongodb

Как получить длину массива versions у документа с _id = 2. Без подгрузки всех данных на сервер.

```
    { 
        "_id" : "2", 
        "versions" : [
            {
                "userName" : "Ivan", 
                "time" : ISODate("2019-09-04T14:44:45.890+0000"), 
        }]
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [агрегацию](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/):

```
versions_count =  db.user_versions.aggregate([
    {$match: {"_id": "2"}},
    {
        $project: {
            size: {$size: '$versions'}
        }
    }]);
```

Вернется объект такого вида:

```
{ "_id" : "2", "size" : 1 }
```

А дальше достаньте поле size:

```
versions_count.size
```

Comment: А что происходит при агрегации в таком случаи? Сколько записей будет прочитано. Если записей в коллекции будет несколько миллионов, а в каждой еще десятки тысяч версий.

Comment: Более подробно о том, как выполняется запрос, вы можете узнать использовав команду - db.collection.explain("executionStats").aggregate(..). Могу предположить, что будет использована выборка по индексу (IDHACK), а значит 1 запись будет прочитана.